# Why was this line from "You're a Mean One, Mr. Grinch" removed in Hawkeye?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, hawkeye-2021

The end credits of Episode 5 of *Hawkeye* are set to "You're a Mean One, Mr. Grinch", referencing both the show's Christmas setting and

> Wilson Fisk, who was revealed at the end of that episode to be the series' main villain.

The second verse of the song goes like this:

> You're a monster, Mr. Grinch
> Your heart's an empty hole
> Your brain is full of spiders, you've got garlic in your soul,
> Mr. Griii~iiinch
> I wouldn't touch you with a... thirty-nine-and-a-half-foot pole!

However, the version that plays in *Hawkeye* omits the last line of the verse, and instead repeats the last line of the first verse:

> You're a bad banana with a... greasy black peel!

It felt (and still feels) very weird and arbitrary of Disney to remove that one line and *only* that one line, but I assume there must have been a reason behind it.

Is there an official explanation for why the lyrics were altered?

Comment: Did you check whether they might have used a cover that had already replaced it?

Comment: Maybe they wanted it timed out a certain way

Comment: @Adamant [IMDb lists it](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10166584/soundtrack?ref_=tttrv_ql_7) as being the original 1966 version of the song, as performed by Thurl Ravenscroft.

Comment: Probably a health and safety thing — if you’re going to try to touch Wilson Fisk, a 39 ½ foot pole is a decent safety precaution.